# telnet connection to a c# socket doesn't close

Tags: c#, sockets, telnet

I have a c# socket based server which serves TCP clients.
I use telnet based monitoring to see if the server is listening.
to versify clients are up i use server keep alive (sending a random string data), and if socket expection raises-i remove the client from a client's dictionary.
the probelm is: the telnet connections to the socket doesn't get removed from the list of connections and the number of clients is rising up slowly but surely.
i tried a telnet manually to the server through command line and than closing the telnet connection-nothing.the server just keep sending the keep alive to the telnet connection with no execptions.
this is my read call back:

```
 protected void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        String content = String.Empty;
        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
        // from the async state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.socket;
        if (state.socket == null)
            return;
        if (!state.socket.Connected)
            return;

        int id = state.id;
        try
        {
            // Read data from the client socket.
            int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                string newAddedStr = string.Empty;
                newAddedStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                //cut the new message and add it 
                if (state.sb == null)
                    state.sb = new StringBuilder();
                    state.sb.Append(newAddedStr);
                // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                //add data until end of XML
                content = state.sb.ToString();
                //IF GOT FULL MESSAGE FROM SOCKET
                if ((content.Length > 0) /*&& (content.IndexOf("\0") > -1)*/)
                {
                    String strh = String.Format("Client # {0} data: ", id);
                    strh += content.Replace("\0", "");
                    if (!strh.Contains("keepalive"))
                        LogWriter.Trace(strh, "");
                    // l(writeToGetTextBoxMsg), new object[] { strh });
                    if (state != null)
                    {
                        if (state.sb == null)
                            state.sb = new StringBuilder();
                        state.sb.Length = 0;
                    }
                    //add the rest of the xml


                    string objData = content.Replace("\0", "");
                    string xmlData = objData.ToString();
                    try
                    {


                        if (xmlData.Contains("Unsubscribe"))
                        {
                            RemoveSubscriber(xmlData);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (xmlData.Contains("Subscribe"))
                            {
                                if (!state.IsInitiated)
                                {
                                    state.Init();
                                    state.socketClient.OnSocketError += new SocketErrorHandler(socketClient_OnSocketError);
                                    state.socketClient.clientSocket = handler;
                                }
                                AddSubscriber(xmlData, state);
                            }

                        }
                        xmlData = null;
                        objData = null;
                        content = null;

                    }
                    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
                    {
                        LogWriter.Trace(newAddedStr,"ArgumentOutOfRangeException in ReadCallback");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        LogWriter.TraceError(ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace + " " + newAddedStr);
                    }
                    #region oldCode

                    #endregion
                }
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(this.ReadCallback), state);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException es)
        {
            closeSocket(state, false, "Execption:" + es.Message + "," + es.StackTrace);
            if (es.ErrorCode != 64)
            {
                LogWriter.Trace(string.Format("Socket Exception: {0}, {1}.", es.ErrorCode, es.ToString()), "");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            closeSocket(state, false,"Execption:"+e.Message+","+e.StackTrace);
            if (e.GetType().FullName != "System.ObjectDisposedException")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.StackTrace);
                LogWriter.Trace("Exception Message: " + e.ToString() + e.StackTrace, "");
                Console.WriteLine("Exception Message: " + e.ToString());
                LogWriter.Trace("ReadCallback:" + e.Message + " " + e.StackTrace, "ERROR");
            }
        }
    }
```

any ideas?

Comment: If you do a netstat on the server computer *and* the client computer, is the connection still set as established?

Comment: I don't quite follow what's the meaning in the answer.i'm a bit weak at netstat. i ran netstat it seems still established.

Comment: If it's still established at both the client and the server neither has performed a close on the socket. Are you completely sure that either side actually performs a close?

Comment: I've closed the telnet window (cmd) and tried to perform a quit command on the telnet. i'm sure it still established even without the netstat because sending data from the server socket did not fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do a read of a socket and 0 is returned you know that the other side of the connection has closed. Are you doing that?

Comment: No. i've added my read call back to the question. usually i close a socket when the serve keep alive fails.

Comment: what is the meaning of closing connection when 0 bytes are read? why doesn't the keep alive from the server?

Comment: To close when you read 0 bytes from a Read call allows you to avoid using keep alive. Have in mind that if you are not designing your own protocol you wouldn't be able to send keep alive most of the time. And don't rely on TCP keep alive because they are optional and aren't used widely.